# How to make the Enter key work like Tab in ASP.Net applications?

Tags: asp.net

I have written a program. When I hit the Enter key, I want the cursor to move between the textboxes as if I had hit the tab key.  How can I do that in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with JavaScript, I recommend jQuery:

Should be fairly basic. Create a `keyboardeventlistener` for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and then from there trigger a keyboard event for the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Something like this:

```
keyboardeventistener(Enter key) {
    jQuery.Event("tab");
}
```

Comment: @Baconbeastnz-first of all thanks for your interesting.Is there that feature on Textbox?So,How can I write it inside Textbox?

Comment: jQuery is the route to go; if you use regular javascript, you would have to consider the slight variations on the browsers